# Phonegap inappbrowser Load Error

Tags: cordova, load, inappbrowser

I have a simple application with the plugin InAppBrowser plugin with the following link in the Index.html:

```
<a href="#" onclick= "window.open( %URL%, '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes')> CLICK HERE </a>
```

If i set %URL% to be http://www.google.com google page is open in the in app browser.
If url is a page like https://signin.lexisnexis.com/lnaccess/app/signin/aci/la i get the message "Load Error" in the menu bar.

Does anyone knows why is this happening?